# I am facing a problem with python datetime objects, specifically the datetime.timedelta()

Tags: python, django, python-datetime, timedelta

I am trying to find the difference in days as a number and not a datetime.timedelta() instance. I am using Django version 3.2 and fetching date values from a form on a template

[**Assume all the neccesary libaries are imported because its not an import error  i am facing here**]

here is the code from the template - dateform.html

```
<span style="position: absolute; right: 0%;font-size: 0.5em;" class="pull-left">
        <form method="GET" action="{% url 'shifts:timeSheetFiltered' %}">           
            {% csrf_token %} start
        <input type="date" id="start-date"
               name="start-date" >
        end             
        <input type="date" id="end-date"
        name="end-date" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></button>
                </span>
        </form>
    </span>
```

here is the view function in one of the django views.

```
def timeSheetFiltered(request):
    
end_date = forms.DateField().clean(request.GET.get('end-date'))
start_date = forms.DateField().clean(request.GET.get('start-date'))

num_days = end_date - start_date
num_weeks = math.ceil(num_days/7)
week_pack = []
counter = 0
while counter <= num_days:
    week_pack.append(start_date + timedelta(days=counter))
    counter = counter + 1

shifts = Shift.objects.filter(time_added__range = [start_date,end_date])


context = {
    'shifts': shifts,
    'start_date': start_date,
    'end_date': end_date,
    'week_pack': week_pack,
    'num_weeks': num_weeks

}

return render(request, 'shifts/timeSheetFiltered.html', context)
```

Now when trying to process the request, i know the num_days variables is returning a `datetime.timedelta(days={what-ever-the difference-here})` . I do not want that object, how can i extract the number of days as a plain number(Integer) from datetime.timedelta()?
when i run the scripts, I am ending up in the error which  says TypeError at /shifts/timeSheetFiltered/
must be real number, not datetime.timedelta.
and the line being pointed to it  `num_weeks = math.ceil(num_days/7)` cotained in the views.py file i have just shared.

Comment: `(end_date - start_date).days`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **`days`** propery of [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) as

```
num_days = (end_date - start_date).days
```